# Netflix/Conductor does not start up when configured with multiple dynomite hosts on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis

I'm having the following issue, after configuring correctly the dynomite cluster, and setting my server.properties file like:

```
db=dynomite 
workflow.dynomite.cluster.hosts=172.30.0.69:8102:us-east-1a;172.30.0.236:8102:us-east-1a
```

It works well, because both 69 and 236 have redis and dynomite running. Like it should be, just for details, 69 is configured as a data-center1 and 236 is configured as data-center2, and it is replicating normally, there is no problem in the dynomite cluster configuration. But, the interesting part comes now, when I kill redis-server on 69, Conductor does not accept any requests, with the no hosts exception:

```
{code=INTERNAL_ERROR, message=INTERNAL_ERROR - FatalConnectionException: [host=Host [hostname=UNKNOWN, ipAddress=UNKNOWN, port=0, rack: UNKNOWN, datacenter: UNKNOW, status: Down], latency=0(0), attempts=1]redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Storage: Dynomite's current state does not allow this request, instance=ip-172-30-0-97}
```

My question is, since conductor allow multiple hosts, when 69 is down, conductor have to stay up and redirect requests for 236? Another test put me in the same case, changing the 69 with 236, Conductor worked fine, so, seems that he works only if the first host is up.
Another test, when conductor-server is down and just 236 is running and 69 is down, Conductor does not start, it gives the same error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Hi , have you fixed this issue? I am facing same issue.

Comment: No, I've dropped the idea.

Comment: It is an issue for reaching a quorum, have you tested with 3 nodes?